# My PHP fopen() fails to read the final line?

Tags: php, html

I have an account system that reads info from a file. These include (in order) username, password, email, bio, reputation. But for some reason (when I load the data with a series of fgets()) It returns the following error:

> Warning: fgets() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in /home/dsgamesr/public_html/lualessons.x10host.com/userpage.php on line 95.

I made sure that $rep was an item in  the text file. The program proceeds but still resets the $rep variable (and saves it as) blank. The code is as follows:

```php
<?php 

    if (isset($_POST['button1'])) 
    {
        $file=fopen("Users/user".$_SESSION['Username'].".txt","r");
        $user=trim(fgets($file));
        $pass=trim(fgets($file));
        $email=trim(fgets($file));
        $bio=trim(fgets($file));
        $rep=fgets($files);

        fclose($file);
        echo $rep;

        $nfile=fopen("Users/user".$user.".txt","w");
        fwrite($nfile,$user."\n");
        fwrite($nfile,$pass."\n");
        fwrite($nfile,$email."\n");
        fwrite($nfile,$_POST['bio']."\n");
        fwrite($nfile,$rep."\n");
        echo'Bio succesfully updated';
        //echo $user;

    }

?>
```

There is a total of five lines before I submit the new bio and a total of 5 with the final line blank after I submit it.

Comment: You have not opened the file, likely because of permissions.

Comment: You use `$file` all the time, then suddenly `$files` for the last row to read `$rep`. That means the code crashes. Happens to all of us, don't worry :-)

Comment: I must state otherwise; for the file is read correctly for the first 4 lines. It does not emit an error until line 5 (line 95 in full code) And it does set the values. Also, this worked in other pages such as login and sign up (signup creates the file)

Comment: I am so stupid. T.T thank you.